# zsh: killed mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"

Tags: node.js, macos, zsh

I have upgraded my macOS from Monterey to Ventura and now I am constantly, when opening terminal, getting an error:

```
zsh: killed  mkdir -m 700 -p "$SHELL_SESSION_DIR"
```

Then when I run npm script in VSCode, for example with Nodemon package, I get an error:

```
$ npm run start

zsh: killed     npm run start
```

or if I run Nodemon:

```
$ nodemon server.js

zsh: command not found: nodemon
```

I have tried running:

```
brew uninstall git
brew update
brew reinstall pcre2 gettext
brew install git
brew reinstall node
```

but yet problem is still here.